# If one person is praying farz salaat,can another person join him in jamaat?

Tags: salat

As   salaamu alaikum,

One person is praying farz salaat alone. Another person enters and he knows that the person already praying is offering farz salaat.

Can he join him to form a jamaat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

alaikum salaam,

Yes it's fine, there's no difference between Imam of masjid leading prayer from a person who's praying and you join him.  Both scenarios involve similar situations.

[(Sahih al-Bukhari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/120)

Comment: the source you gave is irrelevant to the question.